# How can I process data in a buffer line by line, without copying the data?

Tags: c++, string, memory, buffer, move

I am currently doing something like this:

```
void my_func(std::iostream &a_large_buffer) {
    std::vector<std::string> my_lines;
    for (std::string line; std::getline(a_large_buffer, line); ) 
    {
        // do stuff with line
        my_lines.emplace_back(line);
    }
    // ...
}
```

`my_func` is processing the output of a network request, resulting in `a_large_buffer`. The data I retrieve is potentially large (multiple GBs).

Currently, the code processes the data in the buffer by copying it to strings which will be stored in a vector. The copy process will increase memory usage.

How can I **avoid** this **unnecessary copy**?

**Alternative:** How can I delete the data in the part of the buffer that I already read?

I would like to "free" the data in the buffer after it has been copied to `line`. Or just move it straight away from `a_large_buffer` to `line`.

I could not find a `std::moveline`. Is there a thing like this?

As pointed out in the comments, an easy solution would be to process `line` immediately and not keep it around. Please be aware that this is not an option here. I have to copy (or move) `line` into `my_lines`, since `my_lines` will be passed around to other functions.

**Quick example:**

My thinking is that if I read from the buffer, the content in the buffer will still be there. I would like to change that and delete everything after reading it. I am sure there is a method for it.

[Play with the example here.](https://godbolt.org/z/FPzc2P)

Please be aware that the example uses stringstream and not iostream.

Comment: Where does the data in the stream come from? Is it really read into the iostream buffer all at once?

Comment: And why are you using `std::basic_iostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>` instead of plain `std::iostream`?

Comment: I would guess so since it comes from a network request.

Comment: @User12547645 `std::iostream` is a type alias for `std::basic_iostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>`. It's exactly the same type except much less typing.

Comment: `std::iostream` would work just the same, imho. I am using `std::basic_iostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>` here, because that is what I get as a result from the request

Comment: Okay. Let me replace it with iostream. For me it does not matter, since both are the same

Comment: Do you just want `my_lines.emplace_back(std::move(line));`? That won't copy

Comment: @Kevin Imho that will not help. `line` contains the current line only. `line` was created by copying data from `a_large_buffer`. My issue is that in the end, the data is both in `my_lines` and in `a_large_buffer`. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Ah I understand now, thanks.

Comment: "My issue is that in the end, the data is both in `my_lines` and in `a_large_buffer`". Your question should say that explicitly. Currently, you make no mention of `my_lines`. `line` is not a problem. And in order to answer, we need to know what `my_lines` is there for. Why do you need it at all?

Comment: Where is the data coming from? I assume you are not so fool to put some GBs of text on the STDIN!

Comment: @DivyanshSingh From a network request

Comment: @Nelfeal I will fix that.

Comment: @User12547645 What I am getting is that you want to remove content from the stream once it's read. Is this assumption true?

Comment: No single network request will be able to send back multiple GiB of data in a single network packet. If your program is quick enough (and depending on the peer and what/how it sends its data) you might not even have more than one or a few lines of text in the input buffer anyway.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The problem would still be the same, would it not? The buffer gets filled with data request by request. I read the data, by copying to `my_strings`. Afaik the data in `a_large_buffer` will stick around. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: If that were true, you would not be able to read any kind of large files using standard C++ streams. The buffers are usually rather small, in the range of a few to perhaps a couple of tens of KiB. Once all of the data in the buffer has been read, it's filled with new data from the input source. Worst-case is that the implementation have e.g. a circular ring of buffers to allow putback across buffer boundaries, which might amount to maybe a couple of hundred KiB. In short: This is not an issue you need to worry about. And if you do, then *measure* and *benchmark* and *profile*.

Comment: Thank you for clarification @Someprogrammerdude I will examine my code further to find the bug.

Answer (score 0):

`my_lines.emplace_back(std::move(line));`

Comment: Same comment as above: @Kevin Imho that will not help. line contains the current line only. line was created by copying data from a_large_buffer. My issue is that in the end, the data is both in my_lines and in a_large_buffer. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you need to put everything into a vector. Probably you may use the data right away, instead of piling them up.

Comment: Thought about that, but I think that will not work in my program. The resulting vector will be passed around quite a bit.

Comment: @User12547645 Is this okay if you clear the buffer somehow after the vector's ready? Is that what you want?

Comment: That might be what I want. Is it possible to always clear the part of the buffer that I just read? How would you do that?

Comment: @User12547645 Well I doubt that if it is even possible to do in case of iostream. There must be some workaround but that too will not be without making you shift your "GBs" of data or reversing the content , and that too a thousand times!

Can you get the data in some other form such as a string stream? I think then it might get some easier.

Comment: Possibly. Could you please explain how a stringstream would make it easier?